# How to auto adjust (stretch) div height and width using jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 divs with ids A, B, C and D, like below;

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</div>
<div id="D"></div>
```

Div A & D have fixed width & height. Div B has fixed width. I want the height of Div B and height + width of Div C calculated automatically. I want to stretch Divs B and C in between div A and D. Also I want to stretch Div c in between div B and right margin. The page thus wont be having any scroll bars and empty space.

My expected layout is like below

[image]

How can I make this possible using jquery / css?? Anybody has a solution and pls give me a fiddle / demo ??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: Is the height of the overall structure fixed, or should it expand to 100% height of the parent element? What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: i focus on firefox, but i think, I can have a cross browser support if i calculate the lengths using jquery. Height: 100% won't work in browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, despite asking, I'm still not entirely sure what you want.

I don't think you have to use jQuery for it either. How's this?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4BR9s/)

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#top, #left, #right, #bottom {
    position: absolute
}
#top {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00b7f0
}
#left {
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #787878
}
#right {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #ff7e00
}
#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #9dbb61
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

---

Or maybe you want it like this instead? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4BR9s/1/

Comment: i want the container to fill the screen, ie width and height 100%

Comment: @blasteralfred: I predicted that might be the case. See the second version at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the diagram!

I don't think you need jQuery for this. I know you asked for a specific example for you, but there are several good resources that popped up on Google. Look for 'fluid layout' and specifically here: http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of jquery 'animate':

```
$('your_selector').animate({
'height':'<your_calculated_height>',
'width':'<your_calculated_width>'
},'slow');
```