# CSS float pixels and percent mixed

Tags: css, layout, percentage

Ok, I want this:

[image: Correct layout centered on browser window.]

For that, I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapForCenter">
    <div id="title">
        title
    </div>
    <div id="contentFrame">
        <div id="imagePlaceholder">
            image
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>            
    <div id="buttonsBar">
        buttonsBar
    </div>      
</div>
```

And I have this CSS code:

```
#wrapForCenter
{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-left: -240px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#title
{        
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: Blue;
}

#contentFrame
{
    height: 240px;
    width: 480px;
}

#imagePlaceholder
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Green;
}

#content
{
    float: left;
    width: 380px; /*<-- look at this*/
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}

#buttonsBar
{
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;    
    background-color: Silver;
}
```

If I change the contents width to 100%, why occurs this?

[image: Contents get 100% with of its container but it not respect image width]

What I spect is that content width would be contentFrame minus imagePlacehoder width in pixels, but when I specify float:left for both, imagePlacehoder and content, content gets its parent container width. Why?

Is there another way to get the same result without using float (maybe display:inline)? And using width:100% for content?

Thank you very much. CSS is not my strenght.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a float drop. Floats work such that they'll fit side-by-side as long as there's enough room for each, but a float will bump down below the previous one if there's not enough room for it to fit.

`width:100%` means make it 100% as wide as its container (#wrapForCenter). Naturally, if you tell something to be the *entire* width of it's container, nothing can fit along either side inside of that container, so as a float it must move down below whatever is before it (an earlier "sibling") to fit.

Answer (score 3):

A question similar to this was asked by me myself in stackoverflow before.

[How to auto adjust (stretch) div height and width using jQuery or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566798/auto-adjust-div-height-and-width-stretch)

You can set **HTML** like;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And **CSS** like;

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
#top, #left, #right, #bottom {
    position: absolute
}
#top {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00b7f0
}
#left {
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #787878
}
#right {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #ff7e00
}
#bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #9dbb61
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4BR9s/)*** is the working demo.

Hope this helps..

*Note:* I recommend (not forcing) you to do a search in stackoverflow before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your image holder to 25% and your content to 75%, or if you know how much space you have allocated for your entire content area(picture and content) then subtract 100 from that and use that many pixels. but overall this should work

```
#wrapForCenter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-left: -240px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#title {        
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: Blue;
}

#contentFrame {
    height: 240px;
    width: 480px;
}

#imagePlaceholder {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;    /* See Here */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: Green;
}
#content {
    float:right;
    width: 75%;  /* And here */
    height: 100%;
    background-color:Yellow;
  }
```